# How do I add custom interceptors to my annotation scanned spring-ws endpoint

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

I am using Spring-ws 2.1.4.RELEASE and Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE.
I am trying to add an interceptor to my endpoint but so far no luck even though I think my setup is very basic.

In my Spring-ws XML I have:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
</sws:interceptors>

<sws:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="package.with.my.endpoints" />

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="payloadCaching" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

In my Endpoint annotated bean I use the Spring-ws @Action annotation for ws addressing mapping:

```
@Endpoint("MedicineCardIdwsEndpoint")
public class MedicineCardIdws {
    @Action("http://someuriandversion#GetMedicineCardIdws")
    @ResponsePayload
    public String getMedicineCard(@RequestPayload Element payload, SoapMessage soapMessage) {
        return ""; 
    }
```

However nothing is logged by the interceptor when I send a request for my endpoint. At first I thought I had configured log4j wrongly. However, if I create a breakpoint in the first line of org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.AbstractLoggingInterceptor#handleRequest the breakpoint is never triggered.

Then I put a breakpoint inside org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher#headerUnderstood I can see that the only interceptor that is registered for my Endpoint is the org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AddressingEndpointInterceptor which got added because of the Action annotation.

I thought that any global interceptors in the XML configuration would end up being added to the interceptor chain for all endpoints? However it seems this is not the case. It is not just the logging interceptor, even custom interceptors are not added. So I must be doing something wrong.

I am fairly new at using Spring-ws - did I miss something in my config, or is there an annotation I need to add in order to add interceptors for annotation scanned endpoints?

Is there another way I can add  interceptors to my interceptor chain when using component scanning and annotations for Spring-ws or do I need to configure all of it in XML in order to be certain that my interceptors are added to my endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use @SoapAction annotation instead of the WS-Addressing @Action (bot from Spring-ws packages) my custom interceptors from the XML config will get added to the endpoint.

I also found this thread in the Spring forums suggesting a workaround if @SoapAction is not an option: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/100060-interceptors-not-working-for-ws-addressing-endpoint-action